Adding offset points to points in table in ArcGIS Pro
I have a table of location points. For each point, I need to create four offset points, each 40 feet from the original point and with a specific degree bearing relative to the original point. For example:
I have original point A.
I need

Offset 1 - 40 feet from A at 90 degrees
Offset 2 - 40 feet from A at 180 degrees
Offset 3 - 40 feet from A at 270 degrees
Offset 4 - 40 feet from A at 360 degrees

Note that this is for more than just one point... I don't have just point A, I have points A-Z.
How do I do this in ArcGIS Pro without using ArcPy?

Add geometry attributes. Calculate field Shape using arcpy.Point(point_x+40,point_y) to move points North.

Buffer your points by 40' to get something to test with.

This would be geodetically aware (if the source point is geographic) arcpy.PointGeometry(pointA.firstPoint,pointA.spatialReference).pointFromAngleAndDistance(angle,distance,method)

If your ultimate goal is to link this points check out this tool I had uploaded to esri code sharing.
